# Set label ratio on a Pie with achart engine Android

Tags: android, charts, label, achartengine, pie-chart

I have created a Pie on achartengine but the labels displayed are overlapping. There is a way to set the label ratio on a Pie with achart engine Android?

Comment: I don't believe you without a screenshot and some code. What version of ACE are you using?

Comment: if you look at the picture the numbers are touching each other. If we reduce the image to a cell phone seem to overlap. The problem is not as seen by the programmer, the problem is how the end user sees. To solve this, we need to define a larger radius for the labels. The only data required are the values ​​0,6, 23, 71 

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5dcNCFLLj_3TkdvOENEZEVPN2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Dan!  the problem was that display values didnt have the same distance like the pie labels. Then i had to set the labels (category name) with the values and hide the legend. Finally i have implemented the legend manually out of the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the labels (category name) with the values and hide the legend. Finally, implement the legend manually out of the chart.